# Como faço para adicionar análise em tempo real das visualizações nas minhas perguntas e respostas no SO?

Tags: google-analytics-api

É possível adicionar algum tipo de acompanhamento ou análise ao vivo das visualizações às perguntas e/ou respostas que eu postar aqui no estouro de pilha?

No fundo será que é possível adicionar Analytics a uma página que não é nossa?

Comment: Se puder, confira esta Q&A: [I don't always answer myself, but when I do, I fail to ask a good question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188687/185667). Minha resposta lá não está muito consolidada, mas tem links para vários tópicos que foram discutidos à respeito.

Comment: @brasofilo ainda não li as respostas, mas a pergunta é fenomenal, hahaha.. já vi muito disso, talvez até eu mesmo me encaixe nessa situação, rs, tenho que refletir sobre isso

Comment: And once more here too: Don't use a hidden image to collect data; this violates the terms of service. See [Is it OK for me to track visits to my Stack Exchange profile, questions, & answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192201)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é! Usando uma [imagem sinalizadora](https://github.com/igrigorik/ga-beacon) criada principalmente para [rastrear páginas do github](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-beacon-image-github-website-email-analytics/).

É muito simples, basta seguir os seguintes passos:

#### Instruções de configuração

Primeiro, faça login na sua conta do Google Analytics (se você não tem uma conta do Analytics, no entanto, obter um [aqui](http://www.google.com/analytics/)) e [criar uma nova propriedade](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042508?hl=pt):

- Seleccione "Website", utilize o tipo de rastreamento "Universal Analytics"
- **Nome do Website:** qualquer coisa que queira (e.g. StackOverflow Perguntas e Respostas)
- **URL do Website: https://ga-beacon.appspot.com/**
- Carrega no botão "Obter ID de controlo", copia o ID to tipo `UA-XXXXX-X`na página que aparece a seguir

Em seguida, adicione uma imagem de rastreamento para as páginas de perguntas/respostas que deseja acompanhar:

- `https://ga-beacon.appspot.com/UA-XXXXX-X/tipoConta/nome_pergunta`
- `UA-XXXXX-X` should be your tracking ID
- `accounttype/question_name` is an arbitrary path.

Adicione esta imagem à sua pergunta/resposta (se você tiver ambos na mesma página, escolha apenas um), e está pronto!

Aqui está o exemplo utilizado para esta página:

```
    ![Beacon][1]

    [1]: https://ga-beacon.appspot.com/UA-50149210-2/PT_StackOverflow/Como_faco_para_adicionar_analise_em_tempo_real_das_visualizacoes_nas_minhas_perguntas_e_respostas_no_SO_QA?pixel
```

Uma vez que está tudo configurado, instale [este painel personalizado](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=MQS4cmZdSh2OWUVqRntqXQ) em sua conta para uma visão em tempo real agradável (como mostra a imagem abaixo).

E o resultado é este:

[image: example dashboard]

---

## Edit 14-05-2014:

Depois de [ser discutido no Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231608/is-it-appropriate-to-add-third-party-tracking-scripts-or-web-bugs-to-individual), devo acrescentar o detalhe a esta resposta que o uso deste farol ou algum semelhante, pode ser sujeitos à aprovação pelos Termos de Serviço do website alvo.

**No caso to SE, isto viola [the Stack Exchange terms of service](http://stackexchange.com/legal), section 3(e):**

> *Subscriber represents, warrants and agrees that it will not contribute any Subscriber Content that ... (e) contains a virus, trojan horse, worm, time bomb or other computer programming routine or engine that is intended to damage, detrimentally interfere with, surreptitiously intercept or expropriate any system, data or information.*

Comment: Me sinto meio defasado... você está dizendo que é possível instalar um Analytics numa página que não é nossa? . . . Na verdade, sua pergunta está muito vaga... a resposta parece fenomenal, mas a pergunta não explica muita coisa do problema que está sendo resolvido.

Comment: Isso mesmo! Adicionar um Analytics numa pagina qualquer que permita adicionar uma imagem em Markdown ou html. ;-)

Comment: Agora mesmo não posso, mas não vejo a hora de testar isto, *muchas gracias!*

Comment: Isso me lembrou um artigo que li em 2011: [Abusing HTTP Status Codes to Expose Private Information](https://grepular.com/Abusing_HTTP_Status_Codes_to_Expose_Private_Information) que utilizando uma técnica parecida consegue mostrar se você está logado ou não em determinado serviço.

Comment: Neste caso não mostra os dados pessoais das visitas mas faz um resumo do geral.

Answer (score 5):

Que tal usar a [API da própria Stack Exchange](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) ?

Olhe só um pequeno fragmento do que dá pra fazer:

```
Api de respostas:
/answers                  Obtem todas as respostas do site
/answers/{ids}            Obtem respostas identificadas por um set de IDs
/answers/{id}/accept      Dá um accept na resposta identificada [precisa de autorizacao]
/answers/{id}/accept/undo Desfaz o accept
/answers/{ids}/comments   Obtem os comentários nas respostas selecionadas pelos IDs
...
```

Na **[documentação](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)** tem muito mais.

> Apontei este caminho como uma possibilidade, pois mesmo que não tenhamos métodos com dados das visuliazações desejadas, seria o caso de sugerir no [Meta da SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sim é também muito bom mas em conjunto com isso agora também tenho dados ao vivo, o que a API se não me engano não oferece... O conjunto dos dois é que dá a visão global para quem o quer! ;)

Comment: Para além disso é um pequeno hack para a malta se manter entretida, visto sendo bastante útil visto que funciona com tudo em que se consiga adicionar links de imagens, adicionei o ao SO mais por exemplo, outros exemplos seriam: emails, forums, repositórios, etc.

Comment: @CMPSoares claro, coloquei mais como um complemento, muita gente não sabe dessa API. Inclusive você pode usar esta API pra colocar suas imagens de rastreamento automaticamente. MAS eu sugeriria você por a imagem apontando para um PHP ou ASP seu, em vez de enviar os dados para terceiros (apesar da interface "bonitinha" já pronta)

Comment: Sim eu sei, mas a parte gira é que é OpenSource e consigo ir lá controlar o repositório. Para estas brincadeiras não acho que tem importância, mas concordo que se for para situações como por exemplo dados para fins comerciais ou profissionais já teria que criar o meu...

Comment: Isso é giro! Quando tiver mais tempo quero fazer umas brincadeiras com isso, por agora, é só assim! Estou muito atarefado com a faculdade! :-S

Comment: Estive a ver melhor o API e acaba por não responder a minha pergunta... Ele dá respostas, votos etc e o que se consegue ver na página mas nada que mostre a actividade na página, é uma informação interessante mas acaba por não responder a pergunta... :-/